# What does the sentence mean?

Tags: meaning

> Kaj li diris: Ĝuste do lia nomo estas Jakob, **ĉar li submetis al mi
>   la piedon jam du fojojn**; mian unuenaskitecon li prenis, kaj jen li
>   nun prenis mian benon! (Moseo 1: Genezo 27: 36)

Which is the meaning of the sentence? Or it means other? And why?:

1. ...because he put his foot on my way two times;...
2. ...because he put me beneath his foot two times;...
3. ...because he threw the trap for me two times;...

Answer (score 6):

La traduko estas iomete enigma. Laŭlitere ĝi signifas:

> li **metis** sian piedon **sub** min jam du fojojn

aŭ esence:

> li anstataŭis min [aŭ: stumbligis min] jam dufoje

La klarigo estas:

> Kiam origine donita, la nomo Jakob estis vortludo pri la vorto *kalkano* (Gen 25:26). La nomo (ĉar ĝi estas verbo) verŝajne posedas la signifon "ke li protektu!" aŭ simile; tio estas, kiel posta gardisto, tuj sekvanta la kalkanojn. Oni verŝajne elektis la nomon pro la tuja asociado kun la incidento de kalkanokapto. Esav donas al la nomo "Jakob" malbonan kromnocion ĉi tie, la signifon "stumbligi, anstataŭi."

---

The translation is a little puzzling. Literally it means:

> he has put his foot beneath me twice

which essentially means:

> he has supplanted [or: tripped me up] me twice

The explanation is:

> When originally given, the name Jacob was a play on the word “heel” (see Gen 25:26). The name (since it is a verb) probably means something like “may he protect,” that is, as a rearguard, dogging the heels. This name was probably chosen because of the immediate association with the incident of grabbing the heel. Esau gives the name “Jacob” a negative connotation here, the meaning “to trip up; to supplant.” [Notes to NET Bible](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Genesis+27)

Answer (score 5):

This is an interesting sentence. I suspect it's a literal translation of a Hebrew idiom. I would understand it to mean "because he put his foot under me."

It's interesting to note that some English translations have this as "because he cheated me" and "because he supplanted me." The word "supplant" is related to the Esperanto words "sub plando" and historically meant "to trip up" but now means "to replace."

"Jacob" means "holder of the heel" which is why the translators have looked for foot-related expressions to translate this passage.